# Screen recording of user experience in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, screen-recording

I want to screen record my users usage that will be embeded in my react code, this is private company website.

MediaStream Recording of mozila is "asking" for premission to get record.

there is any solution for that?

Edit:

I want it to be "behind the scenes", I dont want to bother the agents with not relevant clicks on their system

I'm using it for catching bugs for developing purposes. they say "X doent work for me" I want to visit their flow to improve the development.

Comment: Without permission it would be considered illegal in most countries.

Comment: @jabaa because I want it to be "behind the scenes", I dont want to bother the agents with not relevant clicks on their system

Comment: @jabaa I'm using it for catching bugs for developing purposes. they say "X doent work for me" I want to visit their flow to improve the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible.

eg. https://www.inspectlet.com/  does this, and doesn't require special permissions.

They basically work by capturing DOM mutations.
There are Open Source alternatives too.  eg. https://github.com/Pernosco/DOMRec

They might be legal issues to consider, but in theory capturing the DOM mutations of your own website I wouldn't expect would cause many issues, especially if this is for Debugging or Internal reasons.

Capturing more than your own website, would of course require special permissions, like MediaStream Recording can do as this could capture more than your own website.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped!